# How can I modify the text in the MUI_UNPAGE_COMPONENTS for the text left of the components box?

Tags: installation, nsis

The problem I am having is that the Install and Uninstall Components page is both displaying the caption "Select components to install" I would like this to be "Select components to uninstall" when I am uninstalling. Unfortunately I have not found how to do this from reading the MUI documentation or anything on XPUI. I hope it is something I am overlooking and that this can be done. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code below is an example that is very close to what I am using for my install and uninstall pages. XPUI is being used, AFAIK the MUI commands are converted too XPUI at compile time.

**Example code**

```
; Welcome page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
; License page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "License"

;show the component page
!define MUI_COMPONENTSPAGE_NODESC ;Hide the description box
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS

; Instfiles page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

;Confirm uninstall page
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM

;Allow user to select components to uninstall
;This is where I would like to change the text of the page ------------------
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_COMPONENTS

;Uninstall page
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
```

Comment: You tag says MUI but you also talk about XPUI, can you confirm which UI library you are using?

Comment: Sorry I am using XPUI

Comment: I don't know if anyone here is familiar with XPUI, I know I'm not but posting some example code might be helpful...

Comment: If a normal MUI uninstaller does not have the same problem then it might be a XPUI bug and you probably need to contact the author...

Comment: Ahh ok, thanks for your help!